# Java program "Error: Could not find or load main class Control"

Tags: java

I wrote a java program:

```
$ cat com/oca/controll/Controll.java
package com.oca.controll;

public class Controll {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    ...
    }
    public static void change(Adult adult, int age){
    ...
    }
}

class Adult{
...
}
```

and compiled it successfully:

```
$ javac -d output com/oca/controll/Controll.java
$ ls -l output/com/oca/controll
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 abc  483 Jan  9 10:34 Adult.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 abc 1029 Jan  9 10:34 Controll.class
```

when I tried to execute it, it gave the following error:

```
$ java -cp output/com/oca/controll com.oca.controll.Controll

Error: Could not find or load main class com.oca.controll.Controll
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Is `control` vs `controll` a typo only in the question or also in your code?

Comment: Try it with `java -cp output com.oca.controll.Control` - your package is not part of the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

This will execute you class

```
 java -cp output com.oca.controll.Control
```